# Trying to use Redis Sentinel with Net Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, redis, stackexchange.redis

Well, I'm using `Net Core 2.1` with lib `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis ver 2.1.2`, and when I'm working with only one Redis node, everything works fine.

Working with single node:

```
services.AddDistributedRedisCache(ops =>
            {
                ops.Configuration = "localhost:6379";
                ops.InstanceName = "master";
            });
```

But now, I'm trying to use Redis with Sentinel, so I changed my configuration to (following this guide https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Configuration.html):

```
 services.AddDistributedRedisCache(ops =>
            {
                ops.Configuration = "localhost,serviceName:mymaster";
                ops.InstanceName = "master";
            });
```

So, I have a docker-compose.yml to startup redis nodes with sentinel:

```
version: '2'
services:
  redis-master:
    image: bitnami/redis:5.0
    environment:
      ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
      REDIS_REPLICATION_MODE: 'master'
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
  redis-slave1:
    image: bitnami/redis:5.0
    environment:
      ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
      REDIS_REPLICATION_MODE: 'slave'
      REDIS_MASTER_HOST: redis-master
    depends_on:
      - redis-master
    ports:
      - '6380:6380'
  redis-slave2:
    image: bitnami/redis:5.0
    environment:
      ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
      REDIS_REPLICATION_MODE: 'slave'
      REDIS_MASTER_HOST: redis-master
    depends_on:
      - redis-master
    ports:
      - '6381:6381'
  redis-sentinel:
    image: bitnami/redis-sentinel:5.0
    environment:
      REDIS_MASTER_HOST: redis-master
      REDIS_SENTINEL_DOWN_AFTER_MILLISECONDS: 10000
    ports:
      - '26379:26379'
```

When I startup my application everything works fine, so I shutdown the master node to test sentinel and got the following error in Asp Net Core:

```
RedisConnectionException: SocketClosed on localhost:6379/Subscription, origin: ProcessReadBytes, input-buffer: 0, outstanding: 0, last-read: 14s ago, last-write: 14s ago, unanswered-write: 1998113s ago, keep-alive: 60s, pending: 0, state: ConnectedEstablished, in: 0, ar: 0, last-heartbeat: 0s ago, last-mbeat: 0s ago, global: 0s ago
Unknown location

RedisConnectionException: No connection is available to service this operation: EVAL; SocketClosed on localhost:6379/Subscription, origin: ProcessReadBytes, input-buffer: 0, outstanding: 0, last-read: 14s ago, last-write: 14s ago, unanswered-write: 1998113s ago, keep-alive: 60s, pending: 0, state: ConnectedEstablished, in: 0, ar: 0, last-heartbeat: 0s ago, last-mbeat: 0s ago, global: 0s ago
StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ThrowFailed<T>(TaskCompletionSource<T> source, Exception unthrownException) in ConnectionMultiplexer.cs, line 2000
```

Well, if I start master node again, everything works, but this is not expected behavior. I expected that after shutdown master node, sentinel promote a slave to master, and I can continue using redis without errors.

Am I missing somehting ?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late reply, but we're just getting this going ourselves. When connecting to Sentinel, you need to specify the port in your connection string:

```
services.AddDistributedRedisCache(ops =>
{
    ops.Configuration = "localhost:26379,serviceName:mymaster";
    ops.InstanceName = "master";
});
```

Once the ConnectionMultiplexer connects to the Sentinel node, it gets the master node and uses it. Also, I have found that several settings are necessary to make this work:

```
redisOptions.TieBreaker = "";
redisOptions.AbortOnConnectFail = false;
redisOptions.AllowAdmin = true;
```

We are also using StackExchange.Redis v2.2.4 on .NET Core 3.1